# Pandas xlrd engine passed still value error

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlrd

I am trying to read an xls file from a url:

using requests :

```
page = requests.get(url) # xls url
df = pd.read_excel(page.content,engine = 'xlrd')  #engine is passed



File "f:\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "f:\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 230, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "f:\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 296, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Must explicitly set engine if not passing in'
ValueError: Must explicitly set engine if not passing in buffer or path for io.

# if i put in random engine name it throws an unsupported engine error but with xlrd it throws must set engine
```

I tried saving the file and then reading it:

```
with open('file.xls','wb') as f:
    f.write(page.content)

df = pd.read_excel('file.xls',engine='xlrd')  #this works
```

EDIT:

I have tried passing page.text it raises:

```
ValueError: embedded null character
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the first argument to `pd.read_excel` is a `str`, it is interpreted as the *path* to a file (or a URL).  If we wish to pass the content of the file directly to
`read_excel`, then we need to wrap the content in a `BytesIO` to make it a
file-like object:

Therefore, use

```
BytesIO = pd.io.common.BytesIO
df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(page.content), engine='xlrd')
```

Comment: My mistake. I forgot that `read_excel` would interpret a bare `str` as a file path. To pass content, wrap the content in a `StringIO` to make it a file-like object.

Comment: StringIO does not work, but BytesIO did the work, I don't understand, page.content was byte, Why did wrapping in BytesIO work?

Comment: I had thought (though perhaps wrongly) that in Python3 the `pd.read_*` functions expected `StringIO`s, but in Python2 the same functions expected `BytesIO`s. Perhaps I am wrong and `pd.read_excel` always expects `BytesIO`s.

Comment: Here is an example which seems to suggest that wrapping byte content in `BytesIO` is the way to go when using `pd.read_excel`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48326707/190597

Comment: Ah, [the source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/excel.py#L371) hints that data should be kept as `bytes`: "# If io is a url, want to keep the data as bytes..."